# Keyboard on pop-up, covers the primary and secondary buttons in ContentDialog (UWP win 10)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, keyboard, uwp

I am developing a UWP app for windows 10. I have created a content dialog with two text boxes. I have set the MinHeight of the content dialog to Max so that it does not shrink when the keyboard pops-up(when clicking into any of the textboxes). The two buttons (primary and secondary) are at the bottom. When I click into any textbox the keyboard pops-up and it covers the two buttons at the bottom. Is there any way I can shift the keyboard slightly upward so that the two buttons remain visible at the bottom even when the keyboard is popped up?

Comment: As far as I known, you cannot do that.